# Display webService Response on tableview in swift

Tags: swift2

How to display web service response on table. It's working when I print the response but how to display it on `tableView`.

I have no idea. Can anyone please help me.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displyResponse()
    }

    func displyResponse(){
        let iTuneSite = "http://www.apple.com/itunes/"
        let url = NSURL(string: iTuneSite)

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            print( "\(response)")       
        }
        task.resume()       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use subclass of UITableViewController, store response in some instance variable (`var itemsToDisplay: [SomeObject]`) and override following methods:

```
numberOfRowsInSection(_:)
numberOfSections
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

1. returns number of sections in your table, probably 0
2. returns
   number of items you want to display. Normally return
   `itemsToDisplay.count`
3. configure cells

When your task is completed just convert and store response in `itemsToDisplay` variable

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        self.itemsToDisplay = response // transform response here
        self.tableView.reloadData()      
    }
```

There are a ton of tutorials in the internet.

Comment: It is just a pseudocode, you must transform raw response object (probably JSON) and construct an array

Comment: And please, do not edit my answer and paste your code here. Do it in your question, because i can't edit my own text now without reject your changes